# How to format log4j timestamp with nanoseconds and timezone?

Tags: java, log4j

I want to achieve a timestamp that has nanoseconds and time zone difference, example:

> 2021-11-30 22:21:41.829798+02:00

I failed with variations like:

> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnXXX}

Dependency:

```
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.11.0</version>
```

Is that supported with log4j and if so how can I achieve that?

thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation? Entire format is clearly described with all the options.

Comment: @MirekPluta Hi, I have updated my question to include the dependency I am using...
Yes I have looked into documentation and did not find any indication for using both nanoseconds and timezones..
I would greatly appreciate if you can refer me to the right documentation perhaps I was looking at the wrong place.

Comment: FYI, Your desired format complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Tip: For logging, adjust to an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds for consistency.

Comment: I don’t use log4j, but I am guessing that `org.apache.log4j.helpers.ISO8601DateFormat` might help.

Comment: @BasilBourque Hi, unfortunately I did not find any reference for nanoseconds in the page you linked. also not in the documentation of this class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find an obvious solution :)

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn}%d{XXX}
```

I separated the timestamp with nanos from the timezone itself and it worked.